# Java/Priority queue and constructors and type

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I don't underatnd a few things about this next line

```
PriorityQueue<D> myList = new ImplementPriorityQueue<D>(K + 1);
```

`PriorityQueue<D>` is an object, like a integer for exemple, that is a "PriorityQueue" a linked list (because of the <>) that has elements of type D ( D is a generic term). And  ImplementPriorityQueue is a constructor, also a linked list?
But shouldn't the object and and the constructor have the same name?

also, the constructor allows you to construct the object and then being able to use the functions written in the construcor ? Is that right?

Comment: `PriorityQueue<D>` is the type of the variable. `ImplementPriorityQueue<D>` is the type of object being created.

Comment: it is the same as `Object o = "test"` The object itself is just a superclass of a String in this case, where `PriorityQueue` seems to be the superclass of `ImplementPriorityQueue`

Comment: but <> doesn´t mean it´s a linkedlist?

Comment: @christinejakotte `<>` is just a operator, that tells you the class is expecting a generic, this is not a thing that only `LinkedList` do use. You could implement it by yourself in any basic class aswell

Answer (score 0):

`PriorityQueue` is a class, not an object.

`myList` is an object of type `PriorityQueue`, with generic type `D`.

`ImplementPriorityQueue` is the actual type of the object, in this case a sub-class of `PriorityQueue`.

`new ImplementPriorityQueue<D>(K + 1)` causes the instantiation of the object assigned to `myList`, using the constructor with the signature `ImplementPriorityQueue(int)`.

Incidentally, why are you calling a queue `myList`?  `myQueue` may be less confusing.

**EDIT**
In response to the comment about myList having two types...

`PriorityQueue` is the declared type, and so this is what your code will treat it as.  It has methods like `peek`, `contains`, etc, and these are all accessible to your code.

`ImplementPriorityQueue` is the actual type of myList.  It may have methods like, just for an example, `explode`, `makeIceCream`, etc, but your code will **not** have access to these methods because it thinks of myList as a `PriorityQueue` - and those methods don't exist in `PriorityQueue`.

It's always a good idea to as general as possible - but no more general when building your code.  Let's look at an example of a method that loops over a list of strings and prints the values.

```
public void printValues(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

You could call this method by passing it an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
printValues(list);
```

This would work fine...but what if you also have LinkedLists in your code?  The following code wouldn't compile, because `printValues` expects an ArrayList.

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
printValues(list);  <--- compilation error here
```

The way to design for this is to use a more general version of both ArrayList and LinkedList.  Both of these classes extend AbstractList, so we could change it to this.

```
public void printValues(AbstractList<String> list) {
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Now, we can pass it LinkedLists, ArrayLists and anything else that extends AbstractList.  **However**, we can improve this further because `AbstractList` is really an implementation detail.  What we really care about is Lists, and so what we should really be looking at is the interface that defines List-like behaviour.  This is java.util.List, and our final version of the method looks like this.

```
public void printValues(List<String> list) {
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Now, because we work with the definition and not the actual type we have a much more useful method that will take anything that implements `List`.

This behaviour is called polymorphism - we can treat an object of type A as an object of type B as long as there is a parent/child relationship between them.  This is why you can treat anything as an Object, because Object is the parent of everything.

As for things being as general as possible, but no more possible - `List` is as general as you can get for Lists.  You wouldn't say, for example, "well, Object is even more general!".

Comment: but why does the myList has two types PriorityQueue and ImplementPriorityQueue ? it's like saying an object is a string and a double for exemple... i don't  understand this part

Comment: myList has a declared type, which is `PriorityQueue` and an actual type, which is `ImplementPriorityQueue`.   I'll update my answer for detail.

Comment: so `ImplementPriorityQueue` is kind of a sub type of `PriorityQueue`?

Comment: @christinejakotte yes - see updated answer.  You can think of  `ImplementPriorityQueue` as an `ArrayList`, `PriorityQueue` as `AbstractList` and `List` as `Queue` (Queue being the interface that is implemented by the Queue types you're using).

Comment: thank you. and what does `public static <E extends Comparable<E>>  MyList<E>` mean at the begining of a class? it means that E will be always a generic element and that we can apply to it the methods of class Comparable?

Comment: It means that when the generic type of E is set, i.e. `new MyList<Something>`, "Something" has to implement the Comparable interface.  So, you could use `new MyList<String>` because String implements Comparable.  You could not use `new MyList<InputStream>` because InputStream does not implement Comparable.

Comment: when you mean "strings **implements** comparable", you mean that we can use string if we use the Comprable interface?

Comment: String already implements Comparable, as do various other classes such as Integer, Date and so on.

Answer (score 0):

From [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

**Casting** shows the use of an object of one type in place of another type, among the objects **permitted by inheritance and implementations**. For example, if we write

```
Object obj = new MountainBike(); // or Object obj = new String();
```

then obj is both an Object and a MountainBike (or String for later case) -  until such time as obj is assigned another object that is not a MountainBike. This is called **implicit casting**.

In another example, apart from the normal way:

```
Child c = new Child(); // or Parent p = new Parent();
```

we can also use (off-course as per our requirement)

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

Here `Child` class may be extending `Parent` class or any of its sub-class. **Note** - in this scenario, [**Polymorphism**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) comes into picture and it's regular rules will apply.

Comment: but in that exemple there is `public MountainBike myBike = new MountainBike();` ; but couldn t we put `public Bycicle myBike = new MountainBike();` and it would have meant the same thing because MountainBike is a subclass of Bycicle ?  Just like here can't we put `ImplementPriorityQueue<D> myList = new ImplementPriorityQueue<D>(K + 1);`    ?

Comment: Off course, we can write. Basically, you need to go through Polymorphism and Inheritance from Javadocs. Also I have edited my answer.

Comment: but here, as of now, in your exemple p=c no? at least we can say that they are the same kind of object with the same type?

Comment: You can write p = c (for assigning). A reference of parent type can be used in place of child type.

Answer (score 0):

This is called polymorphism, Java uses inheritance to define subclasses of each other in order to provide consistency throughout the classes. In this case PriotityQueue is the declared type, and ImplementPriorityQueue is the instance that is assigned to this declaration. This allows flexibility in using the ImplementPriorityQueue.

E.G - An arraylist can be created like this

> Collection list = new ArrayList();

This is because arraylist extends the collection class. This in turn helps you code, by allowing you to change list implementations at a later date.

E.G

> Collection list = new LinkedList();

This will keep all your code from before consistent with your linkedlist due to the previous arraylist confining to the rules of Collection

Comment: so basically, using "Collection", allows me to change letter my object "list" from arraylist to linkedlist juste because linkedlist is a part of the superclass collection?

Comment: An object can be instantiated to a Declaration of any superclass above and including itself. E.G String is a subclass of Object. So a string may be created like this Object str = new String("JAVA");